# How do I access my xml element in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I have    { id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
} plugins my build.gradle. However, I am not being able to access my xml elements
[image: Code]

Comment: Have you added import for your layout?
`import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.screen_pinview.*`

Comment: Make sure you post your code as text in it's original form instead of an image. Regardless, the synthetic bindings that you're referring to were actually deprecated a while ago in favour of view/data binding, so I would recommend looking into that instead.

Comment: you need to define what ```one``` and ```two``` are

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a variable first before assigning a listener to it .
For eg : If assumed that one is a button , and in the xml the id assigned to it is "one" like this  :

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

As you can see id for the button in the xml file is `one`

Then in your fragment you need to create a variable and assign to it using findViewById before using it : For eg :

```
class PinViewScreen : Fragment(){
// variable one is defined by type Button , you can define it of the type you have //designed it in xml
private lateinit var one : Button 

Now , in your onViewCreated you have to initialize and use it :
override fun onViewCreated(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

     one = view.findViewById(R.id.one)
     one.setOnClickListener(pinClickListener)

}
```

It seems that your project uses kotlin - synthetics, Since they are deprecated I would not recommend you to use that and instead use the above method or viewBinding  / databinding

Comment: how sure are you that `findViewById(R.id.one)` will work here

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin synthetic is deprecated in the latest kotlin version.
So to access the XML id you need to use data binding of ViewBinding.

[for data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding)

[For view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)